# How do I make the content slide back when I click the other tabs?

Tags: css, tabs, css-animations

I know this is probably very basic, but I'm just starting out, and can't figure it out. I've got the animation for the content sliding in just fine, but I need to make it so it slides back off the screen in the same way when any of the other four buttons are clicked. Is there any way to accomplish this, while keeping it looking roughly the same as it does now?

```
body {
background: #adafb2;
color: #8d5b8e;
font-size: 1.4vw;
overflow: hidden;
}

#TopLeft {
position : absolute; left: 2%; top: 2%;
width: 5%; height: 1.6vw;
border: solid #403e46;
border-radius: 0.5vw;
text-align: center; 
padding: 0.5vw 0 0.4vw 0;
background: #f6eddc;
}

#BottomLeft {
position : absolute; left: 2%; bottom: 2%;
width: 5%; height: 1.6vw;
border: solid #403e46;
border-radius: 0.5vw;
text-align: center; 
padding: 0.5vw 0 0.4vw 0;
background: #f6eddc;
}

#TopRight {
position : absolute; right: 2%; top: 2%;
width: 5%; height: 1.6vw;
border: solid #403e46;
border-radius: 0.5vw;
text-align: center; 
padding: 0.5vw 0 0.4vw 0;
background: #f6eddc;
}

#BottomRight {
position : absolute; right: 2%; bottom: 2%;
width: 5%; height: 1.6vw;
border: solid #403e46;
border-radius: 0.5vw;
text-align: center; 
padding: 0.5vw 0 0.4vw 0;
background: #f6eddc;
}

#Slide {
  width: 20%; height: 28vw; max-height: 72%; 
  background-color: #f6eddc;
  animation-name: chacha;
  animation-duration: 2s;
border: solid #000000;
border-radius: 0.5vw;
z-index: 1;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes chacha {
   0%     { position: absolute; left: -21%; top: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;}
  100% { position: absolute; left: 4%; top:0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;}
  }

#Slide2 {
  width: 20%; height: 28vw; max-height: 72%; 
  background-color: #f6eddc;
  animation-name: realsmooth;
  animation-duration: 2s;
border: solid #000000;
border-radius: 0.5vw;
z-index: 1;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes realsmooth {
   0%     { position: absolute; right: -21%; top: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;}
  100% { position: absolute; right: 4%; top:0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;}
  }


#Text {
width: 99%; height: 100%;
position: absolute; right: 0; left: 0; margin: auto;
text-align: center;
overflow: auto;
}

#Text::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

#Text {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; 
  scrollbar-width: none; 
}

input { display: none; }  
input + label { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
input ~ .tab { display: none }       
#tab1:checked ~ .tab.content1,
#tab2:checked ~ .tab.content2,
#tab3:checked ~ .tab.content3,
#tab4:checked ~ .tab.content4,
#tab5:checked ~ .tab.content5, 
#tab6:checked ~ .tab.content6,
#tab7:checked ~ .tab.content7{ display: block; }
input + label {  
padding: 0 1vw;
border-radius: 1vw;
cursor: pointer;
}

<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
<label for="tab1"></label>
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
<label for="tab2"><div id=TopLeft>One</div></label>
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3" />
<label for="tab3"><div id=BottomLeft>Two</div></label>
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab4" />
<label for="tab4"><div id=TopRight>Three</div></label>
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab5" />
<label for="tab5"><div id=BottomRight>Four</div></label>

<section class="tab content1"></section>

<section class="tab content2"><div id=Slide><div id=Text><span class=Drop></span>Test1</div></div></section>

<section class="tab content3"><div id=Slide><div id=Text><span class=Drop></span>Test2</div></div></section>

<section class="tab content4"><div id=Slide2><div id=Text><span class=Drop></span>Test3</div></div></section>

<section class="tab content5"><div id=Slide2><div id=Text><span class=Drop></span>Test4 </div></div></section>
```

Comment: why do you use `@keyframes` you can use `transition` is much more make sense

Comment: I can't get transitions to work when clicking the buttons,  @Mohsen Newtoa

Comment: yeah thats right, so you can use jquery it's a better solution.

Comment: I don't really understand JS or jquery yet, sorry for the trouble @Mohsen Newtoa

Comment: that's ok i'll do it for you and try to learn jquery, it's very easy,

Comment: Thank you!! I'm trying to learn it, I've just recently gotten the hang of CSS, but I'm trying to get better. I'll try my best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

jQuery: Download jQuery from here: https://jquery.com/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("label").on("click", function(){
        var id = parseInt($(this).attr("data"));
        $("#content4, #content5").animate({'right':'-25%'}, 100);
        $("#content2, #content3").animate({'left':'-25%'}, 100);
        $("#content"+id).fadeIn();
        if(id > 3){$("#content"+id).animate({'right':0}, 100);}
        else{$("#content"+id).animate({'left':0}, 100);}
        console.log(id);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
<label for="tab2" id="TopLeft" data="2">One</label>
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3" />
<label for="tab3" id="BottomLeft" data="3">Two</label>
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab4" />
<label for="tab4" id="TopRight" data="4">Three</label>
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab5" />
<label for="tab5" id="BottomRight" data="5">Four</label>

<section class="tab" id="content2">Test1</section>
<section class="tab" id="content3">Test2</section>
<section class="tab" id="content4">Test3</section>
<section class="tab" id="content5">Test4</section>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background: #adafb2;
color: #8d5b8e;
font-size: 1.4vw;
overflow: hidden;
}

label{
border:solid 1px #111;
background:#ffdc73;
color:#000;
padding:5px 10px;
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
}

#TopLeft {
top:10px;
left:10px;
}

#BottomLeft {
bottom:10px;
left:10px;
}

#TopRight {
top:10px;
right:10px;
}

#BottomRight {
bottom:10px;
right:10px;
}
input[type="radio"]{display:none;}
.tab{
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
margin:auto 20px;
text-align:center;
margin-top:-14vw;
width: 20%; height: 28vw; max-height: 72%; 
background-color: #f6eddc;
border: solid 1px #000;
border-radius: 0.5vw;
z-index: 1;
transition:all 2s ease-in-out;
}
#content2, #content3{
left:-25%;
}
#content4, #content5{
right:-25%;
}
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote this answer up yet, but thank you, that worked perfectly! I downloaded it, and will do my best to learn it! You're a lifesaver!